# Why are limits set when deriving kinematics equations?

Tags: kinematics, differential-equations

Why is it that when deriving kinematics equations some need to have limits set? So far this is how I have described it (note that the first few steps are not included in the image):

[image]

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could make the upper limit on either side dependent and independent variables like so: $\int_{x_i}^x a dx = \int_{v_i}^v v dv$, which leads to $a x - a x_i = \frac{1}{2} v^2 - \frac{1}{2} v_i^2$. Here we have found a formula for the position as a function of the velocity given the initial conditions. You give me a final velocity, $v_f$, and I can solve for the corresponding final position, $x_f$.

You could also integrate with no limits as such: $\int a dx = \int v dv$, in which case you need to remember to add a constant of integration: $a x = \frac{1}{2} v^2 + C$. You can then find this constant by evaluating initial conditions: $C = a x_i - \frac{1}{2} v_i^2$, which leads us back to $a x - a x_i = \frac{1}{2} v^2 - \frac{1}{2} v_i^2$.

This is just three ways of doing the same thing. The two ways I've described here find a formula. Your way skipped a step. It found the formula *but then evaluated it* at the final velocity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to start with dependent integrals and a range. An example deriving the simplest of the motion equations:

$$a=\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}\\
a\;\mathrm dt=\mathrm dv\\
\int a\;\mathrm dt=\int \mathrm dv\\
at+c_1=v+c_2\\
v=\underbrace{c}_{c_1-c_2}+at$$

An independent integral brings an unknown constant into the picture. Afterwards, we then must interpret this constant $c$. And the interpretation is simple: $c$ equals the speed when $t=0$; that is, the initial speed. Relabel $c$ to $v_0$ to make this clear, and we have reached the final formula:

$$v=v_0+at$$

Using an independent integral in this way implies that the result covers the full range from the initial moment and up until a later moment represented by the variable $v$. That is a consequence of the mathematical nature/definition of an integral.

You can also start with dependent integrals, as you showed, and add some general limits. Just be aware that the lower limit *must* be the initial moment; otherwise you end at a slightly more complicated result than the motion equations you are used to.